# Intro to Java issues

Tags: java, joptionpane

So obviously I'm very new to this.  I'm taking a CIT 111 course and have hit a speedbump.  hoping I can get some help here.
here is the problem and below is the error message it shows me

```
public static void compareTwo (int user, int comp)
{   
   JOptionPane.showmessagedialog (null," Computer chose \n"
    + "\t          " + comp + "\n");

    if (user == comp)
    {
       wins++;

    }// if

    else
    {
       loses++;

    }// else

 }// compareTwo
```

error message:
Gameplay6.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
       JOptionPane.showmessagedialog (null," Computer chose \n"
                  ^
  symbol:   method showmessagedialog(,String)
  location: class JOptionPane
Gameplay6.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
           loses++;
           ^
  symbol:   variable loses
  location: class Gameplay6
2 errors

if more info is needed please let me know and I will be happy to post the rest of the program if that will help you help me ;)
thanks in advance!!

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ that is, the best person to help you first is you!

Comment: The compiler is telling you the cause of your problem.  It's an easy beginner mistake, but you'll learn this lesson much better on your own.

Answer (score 3):

Java is case-sensitive. JOptionPane does not have a method showmessagedialog.
Use:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...);
```

As @CollinD suggested in the comments, you should declare a variable before using it. If you did not declare them somewhere above your method, you should do it in your compareTwo method:

```
public static void compareTwo (int user, int comp){
      int loses = 0;
      int wins = 0;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...);
      ...
}
```

Comment: Also defining `wins` and `loses` would probably help.

Comment: Btw. the correct word is `losses`, maybe it's just a typo?

Comment: so apparently I was having spelling issues lol.

Comment: thank you all for the help. I now have a working program.